# Linear search code that has to output all numbers in the sentence

Tags: python, linear-search

My linear search has to output the index of all of one character present. So if the sentence is Hello, it would print L is in index 2 and 3.

I'm not sure how to do this.

```
def linear_search(intList,target):
    found = False
    count = 0
    #starting while loop
    while count < len(intList):
        if intList[count] == target:
            print("The character is", count, "on the index.")
            found = True
            #break while loop
            break
        else:
            count += 1

    if not found:
        print("The character is -1.")

    return count

#inputting sentence and character
sentence = input('Enter a sentence: ')
character = input('Enter a character: ')
character_found = linear_search(sentence,character)
```

Comment: Its only printing the first because you are breaking out of the loop as soon as you find the first one.

Comment: Just to clarify I only have to find the character is it is in the sentence more than once, I don't have to print out all the characters. So if the sentence is Hello, it would print L is in index 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

It's only printing the first character because you break out of the while loop. Instead, try this:

```
def linear_search(intList,target):
    found = False
    count = 0
    #starting while loop
    while count < len(intList):
        if intList[count] == target:
            print("The character is", count, "on the index.")
            found = True
        else:
            count += 1

    if not found:
        print("The character is -1.")

    return count
```

Comment: This gives an infinite loop

Comment: count shall always be incremented

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a tuple:

```
def linear_search(intList,target):
    found = False
    count = 0
    for i , char in enumerate(sentence):
        if char == target:
            found = True
            print(i , char)
    if not found:
        return -1
    return count

sentence = input('Enter a sentence: ')
character = input('Enter a character: ')
character_found = linear_search(sentence,character)
```

Output:

```
Enter a sentence: i have a a time
Enter a character: a
3 a
7 a
9 a
11 a
```

Your original code is failing because of the `break` statement in the while loop. However, even if you remove the break you'll get an infinite loop because you never increment the counter if the character is found.